# How do you explain users spike in Gatling?

Tags: gatling

Im doing some stress test using awesome [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) tool. On one my report, I saw strange spike of users:

[image: spike]

As you see, its a large spike. Any ideas why? I dont think its related to my server, as response was ok. The simulation is very simple: just GET the single URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a consequence of a response time spike that caused your virtual users to live longer than usual.

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't we then also have a 'negative' spike somewhere before this 'positive' spike?

Comment: No. Active users are the ones who were alive during a given second. If response time increases, users will take a longer time to complete the scenario, and hence will live longer.

Comment: A negative spike would mean that users suddenly had a shorter life. A reason I see for this would be reaching a limit where the server immediately reject any new incoming connection, i.e. faster than usual response time.